# Custom product field to change product total price in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I added some custom product fields using a Wordpress plugin called WC Fields Factory and wanted to change the price of an Woocommerce product after a field gets some input from the user. 
To do this I've used the following code:

```
// custom product field functions

function save_bracelet_engraving_front_or_back_fee($cart_item_data, $product_id) {
    if(isset($_POST['gravaj_bratara_fataspate_10_lei']) && !empty($_POST['gravaj_bratara_fataspate_10_lei'])){
        $cart_item_data['bracelet_front_or_back_engraving_fee'] = htmlspecialchars($_POST['gravaj_bratara_fataspate_10_lei']);
    }
    return $cart_item_data;
}

function save_bracelet_engraving_front_and_back_fee($cart_item_data, $product_id){
    if(isset($_POST['gravaj_bratara_fata_si_spate_20_lei']) && !empty($_POST['gravaj_bratara_fata_si_spate_20_lei'])){
        $cart_item_data['bracelet_front_and_back_engraving_fee'] = htmlspecialchars($_POST['gravaj_bratara_fata_si_spate_20_lei']);
    }
    return $cart_item_data;
}

function save_necklace_size_fee($cart_item_data, $product_id) {
    if(isset($_POST['marime_colier']) && !empty($_POST['marime_colier'])){
        $cart_item_data['necklace_size_fee'] = htmlspecialchars($_POST['marime_colier']);
    }
    return $cart_item_data;
}

// product hook to add custom product field data in global woocommerce product info object
add_filter('woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'save_bracelet_engraving_front_or_back_fee', 99, 2);
add_filter('woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'save_bracelet_engraving_front_and_back_fee', 99, 2);
add_filter('woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'save_necklace_size_fee', 99, 2);

// custom product field function to rewrite WC product price
function calculate_bracelet_engraving_front_or_back_fee($cart_object) {
    if(!WC()->session->__isset('reload_checkout')){
        // Adding bracelet engraving front or back additional price
        $additionalPrice = 10;
        foreach($cart_object->cart_contents as $key=>$value){
            if(isset($value['bracelet_front_or_back_engraving_fee'])){
                if(isset($value['data']->price)) {
                    /*Before vers 3.0 WC*/
                    $orgPrice = floatval($value['data']->price);
                    $value['data']->set_price($orgPrice + $additionalPrice);
                }else{
                    /*WC 3.0 +*/
                    $orgPrice = floatval($value['data']->get_price());
                    $value['data']->set_price($orgPrice + $additionalPrice);
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
function calculate_bracelet_engraving_front_and_back_fee($cart_object) {
    if(!WC()->session->__isset('reload_checkout')){
        // Adding bracelet engraving front or back additional price
        $additionalPrice = 20;
        foreach($cart_object->cart_contents as $key=>$value){
            if(isset($value['bracelet_front_and_back_engraving_fee'])){
                if(isset($value['data']->price)) {
                    /*Before vers 3.0 WC*/
                    $orgPrice = floatval($value['data']->price);
                    $value['data']->set_price($orgPrice + $additionalPrice);
                }else{
                    /*WC 3.0 +*/
                    $orgPrice = floatval($value['data']->get_price());
                    $value['data']->set_price($orgPrice + $additionalPrice);
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
function calculate_necklace_size_fee($cart_object) {
    if(!WC()->session->__isset('reload_checkout')){
        // Adding bracelet engraving front or back additional price
        $additionalPrice = 0;
        foreach($cart_object->cart_contents as $key=>$value){
            if(isset($value['necklace_size_fee']) && !empty($value['necklace_size_fee'])){
                switch($value['necklace_size_fee']) {
                    case 100:
                        $additionalPrice = 0;
                        break;
                    case 70:
                        $additionalPrice = 10;
                        break;
                    case 45:
                        $additionalPrice = 20;
                        break;
                    default:
                        $additionalPrice = 0;
                        break;
                }
                if(isset($value['data']->price)) {
                    /*Before vers 3.0 WC*/
                    $orgPrice = floatval($value['data']->price);
                    $value['data']->set_price($orgPrice - $additionalPrice);
                }else{
                    /*WC 3.0 +*/
                    $orgPrice = floatval($value['data']->get_price());
                    $value['data']->set_price($orgPrice - $additionalPrice);
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
// custom product hook to rewrite WC product price
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'calculate_bracelet_engraving_front_or_back_fee', 99 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'calculate_bracelet_engraving_front_and_back_fee', 99 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'calculate_necklace_size_fee', 99 );
```

When I add the product in the shopping cart the price changes with the new fee added but if I continue to checkout page the fee is added again. So if let's say I add an extra 10$ for 1 engraving text, it will add the 10$ when adding the product in the shopping cart but if I go to checkout page it will add another 10$ and I have no idea what's causing the problem, I've tried changing the hooks but with no success. Any help/hint is appreciated, thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed the last 3 hooks to:

```
// custom product hook to rewrite WC product price
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_calculate_totals', 'calculate_bracelet_engraving_front_or_back_fee', 99 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_calculate_totals', 'calculate_bracelet_engraving_front_and_back_fee', 99 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_calculate_totals', 'calculate_necklace_size_fee', 99 );
```